How to find a file in a go project
I'm trying to get the []byte from an image, using this functions:
func getAttachmentData(fileID string) ([]byte, errors.Error) {
    path := fmt.Sprintf("../../../../uploads/%s", fileID)

    if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return nil, errors.NewUnexpected()
    }

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewUnexpected()
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewUnexpected()
    }

    fileHeader := &multipart.FileHeader{
        Filename: fileInfo.Name(),
        Size:     fileInfo.Size(),
    }

    fileBytes, err := convertFileHeaderToBytes(fileHeader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewUnexpected()
    }

    return fileBytes, nil
}

But when I run the code, I get an error saying that cannot find the file.
The code struct is like:
The code is in:
src/infra/repository/attach/attachment.go
and the image is in:
uploads/
I tried to use the absolute path, remove some of the "../", change the file, but the error persists. All I want, is to make this function work fine.

It is irrelevant where the .go file is, what matters is the path of the file you want to open relative to the path from where you execute the program.

I tried it too, using the path relative from the main.go path, but no matter how much i change the path, it doesn't work.

After a few tries, i finally get it. Thx
